# Geopipeline Filter(Class not found)

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-spatial

I try to use this line

```
GeoPipeline pipeline = GeoPipeline.start( layer )
                .copyDatabaseRecordProperties( "name" )
                .propertyFilter( "name", "Storgatan" );
```

but its throwen this exception in the line with the .propertyFilter()

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tinkerpop/pipes/filter/FilterPipe$Filter
    at org.neo4j.gis.spatial.pipes.filtering.FilterProperty.<init>(FilterProperty.java:39)
    at org.neo4j.gis.spatial.pipes.GeoPipeline.propertyFilter(GeoPipeline.java:708)
    at foo.App.test(App.java:223)
    at foo.App.main(App.java:282)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tinkerpop.pipes.filter.FilterPipe$Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

I'm using neo4j-spatial 1.9.5 and the same neo4j

Does anyone know whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need the Tinkerpop stack on your classpath. If you're using maven, use this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.tinkerpop</groupId>
  <artifactId>pipes</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you need the blueprints API for Neo4j, use the following:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.tinkerpop.blueprints</groupId>
   <artifactId>blueprints-neo4j-graph</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```